# SonarQube server can not be reached when integrating with gitlab

Tags: gitlab, sonarqube

I am trying to integrate sonarqube with gitlab. I have a gitlab instance running on an aws server .I can access that server from my local but when running via gitlab the gitlab is not able to access the sonarserver .Any pointers for help.

Comment: Are you able to ping the sonarqube server from gitlab server ?

Comment: Where is that SonarQube server located? Is it facing internet or is only reachable from your enterprise intranet (in case you have one)? In case that you already have configured your AWS instance to have access to your intranet... Do you know if there is any kind of Firewall in front of the SQ Server? It could be that your VPN is already taking care of that.